# Uploading image(Storage.put) with BLOB object doesn't work in Amplify javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

here is one simple question.
I'm working on React Native and Amplify.
I want to use amplify storage api for uploading image to S3, and I wrote the code below. (I referd to aws amplify official guide:https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/upload/q/platform/react-native/)

```
          const response = await fetch(selectedImage)
          const fileName = `${uuidv4()}.jpeg`;
          const blob = await response.blob();

          await Storage.put(fileName, blob, {
              contentType: 'image/jpeg',
              })
              .then(data => console.log("data : ",data))
              .catch(err => console.log("err : ",err));
```

After executing above code, one file is uploaded, but it is not an image, it is just BLOB header text.
like this.

```
{"_data":{"size":4455509,"offset":0,"blobId":"1CA6A203-41D8-4934-8B71-68B11F406FD3","type":"image/jpeg","name":"EA715E2D-0B25-4531-8F13-B3BF2DC3892A.jpg","__collector":{}}}
```

I don't know what is the problem.
How can I upload the jpeg image on the S3 bucket?

I expect to upload image, not String on S3 Bucket.